# How To Maintain Shopping Cart State with PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to integrate PayPal's Express Checkout API into a homegrown shopping cart.  I've looked at how to make the proper API calls but what's not clear to me is how I'm able to maintain the state of my cart during the time the buyer is logging into and verifying payment in PayPal.  When control passes back to my application via returnURL or cancelURL, how would the state of my cart have been maintained?  Currently, my cart content isn't written into the db until the order is finalized and paid.  Sorry for the naive question - I'm just not seeing the answer to my question in any of the API docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the use of cookies and temporary data. If the cart is of your own creation, you should use a cookie. A cookie expiration of around a month or two would be appropriate. Bear in mind, on successful payment you would need to void this cookie.